# Как выбрать записи по совпадению значений свойств в Битрикс?

Tags: битрикс

Нужно отобрать задачи, где совпадают значения свойств двух полей "UF_CONTROL_TASK" и "PARENT_ID".

Типа такого:

```
$arFilter = [
    "UF_CONTROL_TASK" => "PARENT_ID",
];
```

Но не работает. Как правильно?

Полный код:

```
$arOrder = [

];

$arFilter = [
    "UF_CONTROL_TASK_VALUE" => "PARENT_ID_VALUE",
];

$arSelect = [
    "UF_CONTROL_TASK",
    "TITLE",
    "PARENT_ID",
    "DEADLINE"
];

$arParams = [

];

if (CModule::IncludeModule("tasks")) {
    $res = CTasks::GetList($arOrder, $arFilter, $arSelect, $arParams);
    while ($arTask = $res->GetNext()) {
        echo $arTask['TITLE'];
    }
}
```

**Запрос-1:**

```
$arFilter = [
    "STATUS" => -1,
    "RESPONSIBLE_ID" => 1433,
//    "=UF_CONTROL_TASK" => "PARENT_ID",
];

$arSelect = [
    "UF_CONTROL_TASK",
    "PARENT_ID",

];

if (CModule::IncludeModule("tasks")) {
    $res = CTasks::GetList($arOrder, $arFilter, $arSelect, $arParams);

    while ($arTask = $res->GetNext()) {
        print_r($arTask);
    }
}
```

Ответ-1:

```
...
Array
(
    [PARENT_ID] => 
    [~PARENT_ID] => 
    [ID] => 240048
    [~ID] => 240048
    [UF_CONTROL_TASK] => 
    [~UF_CONTROL_TASK] => 
)

Array
(
    [PARENT_ID] => 
    [~PARENT_ID] => 
    [ID] => 240050
    [~ID] => 240050
    [UF_CONTROL_TASK] => 
    [~UF_CONTROL_TASK] => 
)

Array
(
    [PARENT_ID] => 240116
    [~PARENT_ID] => 240116
    [ID] => 240117
    [~ID] => 240117
    [UF_CONTROL_TASK] => 240116
    [~UF_CONTROL_TASK] => 240116
)

Array
(
    [PARENT_ID] => 240118
    [~PARENT_ID] => 240118
    [ID] => 240119
    [~ID] => 240119
    [UF_CONTROL_TASK] => 240118
    [~UF_CONTROL_TASK] => 240118
)
...
```

**Запрос-2:**

```
$arFilter = [
    "STATUS" => -1,
    "RESPONSIBLE_ID" => 1433,
    "=UF_CONTROL_TASK" => "PARENT_ID",
];

$arSelect = [
    "UF_CONTROL_TASK",
    "PARENT_ID",

];

if (CModule::IncludeModule("tasks")) {
    $res = CTasks::GetList($arOrder, $arFilter, $arSelect, $arParams);
    while ($arTask = $res->GetNext()) {
        print_r($arTask);
    }
}
```

**Ответ-2:**

```
Array
(
    [PARENT_ID] => 
    [~PARENT_ID] => 
    [ID] => 240044
    [~ID] => 240044
    [UF_CONTROL_TASK] => 
    [~UF_CONTROL_TASK] => 
)

Array
(
    [PARENT_ID] => 
    [~PARENT_ID] => 
    [ID] => 240046
    [~ID] => 240046
    [UF_CONTROL_TASK] => 
    [~UF_CONTROL_TASK] => 
)

Array
(
    [PARENT_ID] => 
    [~PARENT_ID] => 
    [ID] => 240048
    [~ID] => 240048
    [UF_CONTROL_TASK] => 
    [~UF_CONTROL_TASK] => 
)

Array
(
    [PARENT_ID] => 
    [~PARENT_ID] => 
    [ID] => 240050
    [~ID] => 240050
    [UF_CONTROL_TASK] => 
    [~UF_CONTROL_TASK] => 
)
```

Итог - не работает...

Должно быть так:

```
Array
(
    [PARENT_ID] => 240116
    [~PARENT_ID] => 240116
    [ID] => 240117
    [~ID] => 240117
    [UF_CONTROL_TASK] => 240116
    [~UF_CONTROL_TASK] => 240116
)

Array
(
    [PARENT_ID] => 240118
    [~PARENT_ID] => 240118
    [ID] => 240119
    [~ID] => 240119
    [UF_CONTROL_TASK] => 240118
    [~UF_CONTROL_TASK] => 240118
)
```

Comment: А весь свой код можете привести? По фильтру тяжело сказать что именно не так. И что именно не работает? Выдает пустой ответ? Проверяли, что в момент сравнения в `UF_CONTROL_TASK`, а что в `PARENT_ID`?

Comment: Да, проверял. Значения обоих полей одинаковые

Comment: Полный код привел

Comment: скорее всего просто сделайте через 2 запроса.
Вытяните все, соберите их PARENT_ID, и тогда уже этот массив передайте в фильтр.

Comment: А можете показать пример кода?

Comment: Неужели в битриксе нельзя в качестве фильтра применить сравнение двух полей, без 2-го запроса? В SQL это делается элементарно.

Comment: @Сергей вообще-то можно. Перед "UF_CONTROL_TASK" в вашем случае ставите знак "=".

Comment: @Сергей Не работает

Comment: @Сергей Попробуйте убрать знак равно, должен воспринимать без него как равенство, по логике.

Comment: Сработало так: ">=UF_CONTROL_TASK" => "PARENT_ID", но не уверен, что правильно это

Comment: в документации нет знака равно

Comment: странно, работает и такая конструкция: "!UF_CONTROL_TASK" => "PARENT_ID"

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй так

```
  $arFilter = [
        "RESPONSIBLE_ID" => #RESPONSIBE_USER_ID#,
    ];

    $arSelect = [
        "UF_CONTROL_TASK",
        "PARENT_ID",
    ];

    if (CModule::IncludeModule("tasks")) {
        $res = CTasks::GetList($arOrder, $arFilter, $arSelect, $arParams);
        $datas = [];
        while ($arTask = $res->GetNext()) {
            if( $arTask["UF_CONTROL_TASK"] == $arTask["PARENT_ID"] ){
                $datas[] = $arTask;
            }
        }

        print_r($datas);
    }
```

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/283072)

Comment: Изменил ответ по вашему запросу. Проверьте решение